# How to configure routes for a profile controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to configure a route to display a profile page about the user.

At the moment, I've created a custom controller for this page using:

I generated my controller using:

```
rails g controller user-profile
```

and I made corresponding views.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
/user-profile/:id
```

I'm using devise. How do I configure the route for this?

Comment: Could you post a bit more related code? I'm having trouble to understand what your question is.

Comment: Hi benoit, I've reworded it for clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way (the resulting profile will be public):

Add the route:

```
match "/user-profile/:id" => "user-profile#show"
```

Add the related action in your controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

You're then free to use the `@user` variable in `app/views/user-profile/show.html.erb`.

Comment: That's great. Question for you- do you think I should have done it another way altogether? Something more restful, so it ended up being something like /user/profile/:id? Was generating another controller the right thing to do here?

Comment: I'd go for something simpler, like `/users/:id` (StackOverflow seems to do this, for example). As for integrating it in another controller, the devise ones aren't that easy to change, creating another one seems to be the more sensible and clear choice.